Is there a name for the likelihood of the most likely outcome?
In pop statistics, it's common to state what the most likely outcome is as if that is a very meaningful attribute.
But without knowing how likely the most likely outcome is, it isn't really so highly meaningful.
For instance, in four coin tosses, the most likely result is half heads and half tails,
but the likelihood of actually getting that result is only 37.5%; nearly two thirds of the time it will be something else.
With larger numbers of coins, the most likely result doesn't change, but the likelihood of achieving it approaches zero.
That is, the most likely event can be very unlikely.
It seems to be something that is almost never mentioned, but is there a name for this concept of how (un)likely the most likely result is?
(A similar question could be asked for the expected value.)
CLARIFICATION:
I'm not so interested in the actual value itself, but in the way the value can be misrepresented or misunderstood.
E.g. If I remove the ace of spades from a deck of cards, I can truthfully say that the most likely outcome of picking a card at random is red.
Or I could remove all the aces except for the spade and claim that the most likely outcome of a random pick will be a spade.
Both statements are accurate but nowhere near as precise as they sound.
The practical truthfulness, usefulness, value, worth, etc. of those statements is close to zero.
What I'm looking for is terminology for this kind of statistic, which sounds significant but is almost meaningless.

I tend to say "maximal likelihood", but I'm pretty sure I made that term up without consulting any person or reference.

Maximal likelihood sounds right to me, but you must note that likelihood is only defined up to a multiplicative constant and so comparing maximal likelihood values across different statistical models is difficult at best.

The probability of the mode?

“Marginally highest” is a candidate.

@MichaelLew: I wouldn't recommend any variation of "maximum likelihood", "maximal likelihood", etc., because the maximisation in that case is usually done with respect to the parameter rather than the data (which would cause confusion).

@Ben You might well be right about that. To me the maximisation should always be with respect to the parameter value (i.e. with the data fixed at the observed value(s)), so I do not know what you have in mind.

@Ben Aha! I see the issue now. The original question is based on systems where the 'true' value of the parameter is known, whereas in my mind the data is known and the parameters are to be estimated. So, yes, you are correct, there is clearly a possibility of confusion. (Is the probability of the most probable outcome even a likelihood?)

I suppose this is the maximum sampling density ---i.e., the maximum value of the sampling density taken over all possible outcomes for the data.  For a parameterised sampling density with some parameter $\boldsymbol{\theta} \in \boldsymbol{\Theta}$ and sampling range $\mathscr{X}$ it would be defined mathematically as the function $M: \boldsymbol{\Theta} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ given by:$^\dagger$
$$M(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \equiv \sup_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathscr{X}} f(\mathbf{x}|\boldsymbol{\theta})
\quad \quad \quad \boldsymbol{\theta} \in \boldsymbol{\Theta}.$$
In the absence of a parameter, this would reduce to:
$$M = \sup_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathscr{X}} f(\mathbf{x}).$$

$^\dagger$ The supremum here reduces to a simple maximum if the sampling density is continuous, which will be the case for a wide range of problems.

To check my understanding: maximum likelihood is the probability of the data given the model and specifically using model parameter values that maximise that likelihood. However, the OP is not interested in the probability of the data but in the probability of the value at the mode (most likely outcome). This is why maximum likelihood is not the term s/he is looking for. Is that right?

@dariober: Yes, that is correct.

The most likely event may be rendered less and less likely by each extra observation on an absolute scale, but the absolute values of the highest likelihood is only useful when compared to the likelihood(s) of other parameter values (according to the same statistical model) and that comparison is made as a ratio. The likelihood ratios do not get systematically smaller with additional observations, and so the phenomenon that you mention usually has no real consequence for statistical inference.
We typically compute log likelihoods (using addition) in order to avoid having to deal with multiplication of extremely small values.
(@Ben Yes, I do consider the likelihood function to be subject to arbitrary scaling!)
